# How to make site go to www. in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm trying to set up a website in IIS7.

If I type in mydomain.com in the browser address bar - a page is displayed, however if I type www.mydomain.com, I get a 500 error.

Any ideas as to what to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that you probably don't have the binding set for www.mydomain.com on your website.

Click on your website in IIS, on the action pane on the right it will have a clickable link that says Bindings, this lets you edit the bindings. There should be an http binding on port 80 for mydomain.com but it sounds like you don't have one for www.mydomain.com, simply add an Http binding on port 80 with the www.mydomain.com hostname.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. Just so I'm clear - do I need one for each - mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com.

Comment: Yes you need two bindings in total: mydomain.com on port 80 and www.mydomain.com on port 80. Hope that helps.